# iOS 8 Remove today extension

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios8

I created a today extension coded in Objective c and I have decided that I do not want it in my app. I removed the scheme, the target and all the files that were associated with it, yet it remained in my notification center. I deleted the app and it was no longer in the notification center, then when I ran the app again it was back. Im afraid that when I submit the app there will be an empty widget as an option to add to notification center. Does anybody know how I can completely delete the extension from the app? Thanks!

Comment: did you completely clean your previously built app in Xcode?

Comment: in Xcode, under the "Product" menu, there's a "`Clean`" menu option.

Comment: Do you still have an entitlement file somewhere...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I simply did a product clean.

Just press command+shift+k

Now build and run and you should be all good!

Comment: This works on my device, but even after resetting the simulator and deleting the app on it, the widget still shows up. Any thoughts?

Comment: There might still be an entitlement file in the project. Make sure every target that has to do with the today extension is trashed. Do not just remove the reference, trash it and empty the trash. After that do a clean again and reset the simulator. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a little old, but recently I've had a similar problem with WatchKit extension, which kept popping on my Watch when I installed the app on iPhone. In my case it was due to the `DerivedData` folder:

In Xcode open `Preferences->Locations` and go to the `DerivedData` folder and delete everything.

I have also cleaned the project (`cmd+shift+k`) but I'm not sure if this was necessary.

Also if you encounter this problem it is always worth to check the `Target->Build Phases`'s `Target Dependencies` & `Embed App Extensions` shouldn't have any mention of the Extension you don't want to use (or possibly shouldn't even be there if you don't have any extensions or target dependencies.